# Perl regex exclude optional word from match

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strings and need to extract only icnnumbers/numbers from them.

```
icnnumber:9876AB54321_IN
number:987654321FR
icnnumber:987654321YQ
```

I need to extract below data from above example.

```
9876AB54321
987654321FR
987654321YQ
```

Here is my regex, but its working for first line of data.

```
(icnnumber|number):(\w+)(?:_IN)
```

How can I have expression which would match for three set of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace `\w` (that matches letters, digits and underscores) with `[^\W_]` that is almost the same, but does not match underscores:

```
(icnnumber|number):([^\W_]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yI29dF/1).

If you want to make sure `icnnumber` and `number` are matched as whole words, you may add a word boundary at the start:

```
\b(icnnumber|number):([^\W_]+)
^^
```

You may even refactor the pattern a bit in order not to repeat `number` using an optional non-capturing group, see below:

```
\b((?:icn)?number):([^\W_]+)
   ^^^^^^^^
```

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (immediately to the right, there must be start of string or a char other than letter, digit or `_`)
- `((?:icn)?number)` - Group 1: an optional sequence of `icn` substring and then `number` substring
- `:` - a `:` char
- `([^\W_]+)` - Group 2: one or more letters or digits.

Answer (score 4):

Given your strings to extract are only upper case and numeric, why use `\w` when that also matches `_`?

How about just matching:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
   m/number:([A-Z0-9]+)/;
   print "$1\n";
}

__DATA__
icnnumber:9876AB54321_IN
number:987654321FR
icnnumber:987654321YQ
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to get only the values as a match using `\K` to reset the match buffer

```
\b(?:icn)?number:\K[^\W_]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffr815/1) | [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@0OFWhuKQoM7nEmgvELk8sysvMSy@25uLKrVRQAUop2CqoZybn5ZXmJqUWWVlamJs5OpmaGBsZxnv6cSGJgsXcgrhQ1YJFIwPVgeaVZ2TmpGpAjKxT0I9J0rC3AirWtIcqj/GOjosJj4/V1k9X0FSo5lJQKCjKzCtRUFFT0FNQislTsuaq/f8fAA)

For example

```
my $str = 'icnnumber:9876AB54321_IN
number:987654321FR
icnnumber:987654321YQ';

while($str =~ /\b(?:icn)?number:\K[^\W_]+/g ) {
  print $& . "\n";
}
```

Output

```
9876AB54321
987654321FR
987654321YQ
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another suggestion maybe, but *if your strings are always valid,* you may consider just to split on a character class and pull the second index from the resulting array:

```
my $string= "number:987654321FR";
my @part = (split /[:_]/, $string)[1];
print @part
```

---

Or for the whole array of strings:

```
@Array = ("icnnumber:9876AB54321_IN", "number:987654321FR", "icnnumber:987654321YQ");

foreach (@Array)
{
    my $el = (split /[:_]/, $_)[1];
    print "$el\n"
}
```

Results in:

```
9876AB54321
987654321FR
987654321YQ
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression can have 'icn' as an option and part of the interest is 11 characters after `:`.

```
my $re = qr/(icn)?number:(.{11})/;
```

Test code snippet

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/(icn)?number:(.{11})/;

while(<DATA>) {
    say $2 if /$re/;
}

__DATA__
icnnumber:9876AB54321_IN
number:987654321FR
icnnumber:987654321YQ
```

Output

```
9876AB54321
987654321FR
987654321YQ
```

Comment: Note that the dot will match more than the `\w` used by the OP

Comment: You are correct, as of this moment we do not know how 'monotonous' input data. Otherwise we could use `[0-9A-Za-z]` as template for match. `\w` matches more than 100,000 characters in unicode [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 1):

Already you got best and better answers here anyway I trying to solve your question right now.

> Get the whole string,

```
my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> }; #print $str;
```

> You can check the first grouping method upto `_` or `\b` from the below line,

```
@arrs = ($str=~m/number\:((?:(?!\_).)*)(?:\b|\_)/ig);
```

> (or)
>
> You can check the non-words `\W` and `_` for the first grouping here, and pushing the matches in the array

```
@arrs = ($str=~m/number\:([^\W\_]+)(?:\_|\b)/ig);
```

> print the output

```
print join "\n", @arrs;

__DATA__
icnnumber:9876AB54321_IN
number:987654321FR
icnnumber:987654321YQ
```